Analysing distance from coastline between two different datasets in QGIS
I have two point datasets which are animals spotted from the air in different seasons.
Blue: animals observed in April
Red: animals observed in November
This image is a small snip.
How can I analyse the overall distance of these points from the coastline?
I am interested to know if the animals are found closer to the coast during any season.


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. The most frequent comments are, "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If your Question doesn't address these, it is more likely to attract close votes. So, please [Edit] the Question to state what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

If you have a coastline layer, you can use the tool "Shortest line between features". Chose the point layer as input and the line layer as destination layer. The resulting layer contains the input information as well as the distance to the destination layer:

